# Using OverloadedStrings with ByteString type

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I would like to input a string from the console and output a JSON string.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where
  
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Map.Strict
                
main :: IO ()
main = interact $ encode
```

This code fails. Of course, I see `encode` has type `ToJSON a => a -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString` and `interact'` takes `String -> String`, but that's the reason I'm using `OverloadedStrings`.

How can I solve this problem ? Perform a cast to `String` ?

Comment: `OverloadedString`s only works for string *literals*.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you, @WillemVanOnsem. Could you please give me a suggestion for the solution ?

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish here? What behaviour should this program have?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @leftaroundabout. I made a minimal example to illustrate my question. In the end, this program should read string from the terminal, parse each line into a `Map String String` type and encode it as a JSON string.

Comment: @F.Zer: exactly how would the `Map String String` "input format" look like?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I am parsing many lines of text using Hutton's parsing library. In a nutshell, each line has the format "key: value". An arbitrary line could be: "Patient: John Doe", for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OverloadedString`s only works for string *literals*. It thus converts a `"foo"` expression to `fromString "foo"`.

But you can use this to convert this to a `ByteString`. You can first use [**`decodeUtf8 :: ByteString -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:decodeUtf8) to convert the `ByteString` to a `Text`, then use the [**`String`** data constructor of the `Value` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.0.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value), and then encode the data, so:

module Main where

```
import Data.Aeson(Value(String), encode)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Lazy(toStrict)
import Data.Text.Encoding(decodeUtf8)

main :: IO ()
main = B.interact (toStrict . encode . String . decodeUtf8)
```

This will thus convert the input to a JSON string literal.

Comment: Thank you so much ! What's this `Value(String)` ? I've never seen it.

Comment: @F.Zer `Value(String)` will import the `String` data constructor of the `Value` type which is defined in the `Data.Aeson` module.